# how add additional information user in registration firebase ioni7

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

*async signUP function to regestration with email password and fulname regestion is workin but no fullname in database *

```
 async signUP(){
                const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
                await loading.present();
                if (this.ionicForm.valid) {
                  const user = await this.authService.registerUser(this.ionicForm.value.email, this.ionicForm.value.password,this.ionicForm.value.fullname).catch((err) => {
                    this.presentToast(err)
                    console.log(err);
                    loading.dismiss();
                  })
            
                  if (user) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
                  }`your text`
                } else {
                  return console.log('Please provide all the required values!');
                }
              }
```

**for AuthServiceService.ts**

```
export class AuthServiceService {
.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth, } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup, } from "firebase/auth";

import { async } from 'rxjs';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { error, log } from 'console';
import {
  CollectionReference,
  DocumentData,
  addDoc,
  collection,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
} from '@firebase/firestore';
import { Firestore, collectionData, docData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {


  constructor(public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    async registerUser(email: string, password: string, name: string) {
        return await this.ngFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    
      }
```

how to add fullname in Cloud Firestore collection users